# How to solve in angular - type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have variables declared in the **.ts** file:

```
export interface Payment {
     paymentStatus?: string
}
```

In the **component.ts** file, I create:

```
filters: PaymentFilters = {
paymentStatus: null
}
```

In console I get:

**Type `null` is not assigned to type `string`**

and

**type `string | null` is not assigned to type `string`.**

Why do I get such an error when I declare that the variable is a string and can optionally occur?

Comment: Use `undefined` instead of `null`?

Comment: Where does the error occur? What is the function signature for `addToQueryParams`? `function addToQueryParams(variable: Payment, prop: string, value: string): string`?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the optional sign `?` is equivalent to `string | undefined`.
In Javascript as well as in Typescript, `undefined` and `null` are not of the same type.

you should then declared your interface as the following:

```
export interface Payment {
     paymentStatus: string | null
}
```